# Electric field inside a coil

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

What happens to the Coulomb electric field produced by the electron beam moving helically? In principle it would be like considering several rings of charges, in the center of the ring the electric field is zero, but what happens if we cover half of the ring with a material that does not let the electric field pass? then it could be considered as semicircular rings of charges, in the center of this ring the electric field is not zero, am I correct?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you seem to think that the electric field at the centre of the coil is zero because of the cancellation of the effects of field lines there. However, it has nothing to do with that. As conductors are usually neutral in nature, the field anywhere is zero.

Your comment which says "electron beam" brings up a different problem. If you managed to make electrons revolve in a coil-like fashion, maybe using a magnetic field, then we have the following problem.

You talk about a material that "does not let electric field pass". I suppose you are referring to a dielectric material, but if you are, then you are wrong.

A field line, from say a positive charge, extends till infinity unless stopped by a negative charge. Of course, this is an oversimplification but applies for the aspects of this question. So the material you suggest, as far as I know, does not exist. A dielectric material, under the influence of an electric field would polarise and would produce its own electric field and lead to relatively complex fields which I do not think is in the scope of your question. So unless you can think of a material which "stops" field lines altogether without producing its own fields, I think the question is moot.

Answer (score 0):

Most conductors are electrically neutral, i.e., they have equal positive charges (due to atomic nuclei) and negative charges (due to electrons -- charge carriers), for example, in metals. So, the net electric field due to all charges is zero, even as the current is flowing.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I was actually thinking of an electron beam and not "wires"

Comment: In that case, correct the question please for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I already edited it